Vue3 Composition API: Error: Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first when using named slots in router-view
I am currently in the process of rewriting my Vue code in all of my apps but am running into a rather annoying error that I cannot  seem to decipher. Let me explain to you first what I am trying to do.
Imagine I have a global page component with the following named slots:
<div class="page">
     <slot name="header" />
        
     <slot name="content" />

     <slot name="sidebar" />
</div>

In one of my apps that uses this component, I'd like all pages to have the same header but different content and sidebar. I tried the following in my app.js:
<template>
    <Page>
        <template #header>
            my header HTML blablabla
        </template>

        <router-view></router-view>
    </Page>
</template>

And then the following in one of my pages:
<template>
   <template #content>
      my main content blablabla...
   </template>

   <template #sidebar>
      My sidebar content blablabla...
   </template>
</template>

But saving this code gives me an error in my compiler:

Error: Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first.

It seems like this has something do with the fact that I'm using a lot of template tags in a way that Vue doesn't like. But I can't figure out what I can do to work around this. That's why I'm posing the question here. Can anyone help me out with this one? Thanks in advance!

apparently this issue appears when the template is in the wrong spot.

you need default slot:

<div class="page">
     <slot name="header" />
        
     <slot name="content" />

     <slot name="sidebar" />

     <slot/>
</div>

in this case router-view component will be rendered inside default slot. and if you want to render content and sidebar slots inside of router-view which is inside of default slot - you won't make it work.
you need to come up with something else
maybe you need something like this?
<template>
    <Page>
        <template #header>
            my header HTML blablabla
        </template>
        <template #content>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </template>
        <template #sidebar>
            <my-sidebar />
        </template>
    </Page>
</template>

